# Object resets when passed in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have been practicing c++ lately, and came across this exercise where I am struggling a little with reference of objects.

Here is my code:

> ClockUTC.h

```
#include "ClockUTC.h"

ClockUTC::ClockUTC()
{
    hour = 0;
    minute = 0;
}

ClockUTC::ClockUTC(int hour, int minute)
{
    this-> hour = hour;
    this-> minute = minute;
}

int ClockUTC::getHour()
{
    return hour;
}

int ClockUTC::getMinute()
{
    return minute;
}

void ClockUTC::setHour(int hour)
{
    this->hour = hour;
}

void ClockUTC::setMinute(int minute)
{
    this->minute = minute;
}
```

ClockUTC.cpp

```
#ifndef CLOCKUTC_H_INCLUDED
#define CLOCKUTC_H_INCLUDED


#include <iostream>


using namespace std;



class ClockUTC {

private:
int hour;
int minute;

public:
    ClockUTC();
    ClockUTC(int hour, int minute);
    int getHour();
    int getMinute();
    void setHour(int hour);
    void setMinute(int minute);
};


#endif // CLOCKUTC_H_INCLUDED
```

> ClockTZ.h

```
#ifndef CLOCKTZ_H_INCLUDED
#define CLOCKTZ_H_INCLUDED



#include <iostream>
#include "ClockUTC.h"


using namespace std;



class ClockTZ : public ClockUTC{

private:
ClockUTC clockUTC;
int offset;

public:
    ClockTZ(ClockUTC clockUTC, int offset);
    ClockUTC getClockUTC();
    int getOffset();
    void setClockUTC(ClockUTC clockUTC);
    void setOffset(int offset);
};




#endif // CLOCKTZ_H_INCLUDED
```

> ClockTZ.cpp

```
#include "ClockTZ.h"


 ClockTZ::ClockTZ(ClockUTC clockUTC, int offset)
{
    this->clockUTC = clockUTC;
    this->offset = offset;
    clockUTC.setHour(clockUTC.getHour() + offset);
}


ClockUTC ClockTZ::getClockUTC()
{
    return clockUTC;
}


int ClockTZ::getOffset()
{
    return offset;
}


void ClockTZ::setClockUTC(ClockUTC clockUTC)
{
    this->clockUTC = clockUTC;
}



void ClockTZ::setOffset(int offset)
{
    this->offset = offset;
}
```

And here the main file is:

```
/**
   Unit tests for 2nd EOOP assignment.

   ClockUTC - aggregate 2 integers (hour, minute)
   ClockTZ - view for ClockUTC, store reference to clockUTZ and offset

   Note that this is in a big part "code reading" exercise.
   Based on this file you should implement two classes mentioned above,
   with proper interface, and in right header file.
 */

    #include "ClockTZ.h"
    #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
    
        ClockUTC greenwich(9,17);
        ClockTZ warsaw(greenwich, 2);
    
        if (warsaw.getHour() != 11){
            cout << "Error in getHour() 1" <<  endl;
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

I have coded the above files, and the only problem is after creating the ClockUTC class and passing it to the ClockTZ, ClockUTC resets and it is calling it's empty constructor and setting the hour to 0 instead of it's value + the offset as intended. I know it is because that the object is not having any reference and it is being destroyed as soon as passed or something, but don't seem to be able to fix it.

Probably the problem is that ClockTZ has two ClockUTC objects: a base class, and a member variable named clockUTC. The ClockTZ constructor will initialize the member variable by copying the value passed in, and will default initialize the base class. When I later call getHour, the base class is called, returning the default value of 0.

But I do need both in this case...

> Current output: 0
>
> Expected output: 11

I have tried fixing it by applying the & reference, but nothing seem to work. Can someone help me applying it properly?

Here is what I have tried:
`ClockUTC &clockUTC;` as a class member (so the constructor will also have to take its ClockUTC parameter as a reference, then I used the member-initializer-list to initialize it.

As in code:

> ClockUTC &clockUTC;
>
> ClockTZ(ClockUTC &clockUTC, int offset);
>
> ClockTZ::ClockTZ(ClockUTC& _clockUTC, int _offset) : clockUTC( _clockUTC ) , offset( _offset) { }

But this didn't change anything at all, and I still get the same output. Please somebody help me make it work!

**Update:**

```
int main() {

    ClockUTC greenwich(9,17);
    ClockTZ warsaw(greenwich, 2);


    if (warsaw.getHour() != 11)
        cout << "Error in getHour() 1  warsaw " << warsaw.getHour() <<  endl;
    
    greenwich.setHour(11);
    
    if (warsaw.getHour() != 13)
        cout << "Error in getHour() 2 warsaw " << warsaw.getHour() << endl;
    

    cout << "End of tests." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output: 11 and then 13, but it will always be 11. So reference is not working.

**My constructor:**

```
ClockTZ::ClockTZ(ClockUTC clockUTC, int offset)
       : ClockUTC{clockUTC}
{
      this->offset = offset;
      clockUTC.setHour(clockUTC.getHour() + offset);
}
```

Now output will always be 9

Comment: You shouldn't use `using namespace std;`. It's a bad habit and it's especially very bad in a header file.

Comment: Why does `ClockTZ` both derive from`ClockUTC` and contain a `ClockUTC` member variable? That seems extremely redundant.

Comment: Okay so the task says that I have to implement the classes without modifying the unit test which is the main file. So I had to use the base class for the warsaw.getHour(), and then the member variable for the reference that will be modified when constructing the  ClockTZ file as the hour will increase by the offset.

Comment: *But I do need both in this case...* Why?

Comment: @vepew26247 That makes no sense. Either you are just wrong or you are not explaining yourself well enough.

Answer (score 3):

```
class ClockTZ : public ClockUTC{

private:
   ClockUTC clockUTC;
```

This is wrong. `ClockTZ` inherits from `ClockUTC`. It should not have ***another*** instance of `ClockUTC` as a class member. This creates a ***duplicate*** instance of `ClockUTC` that's a private member of the class, in addition to inheriting from `ClockUTC`. Remove this `clockUTC` class member, completely. Just get rid of the `clockUTC` declaration in its entirety.

```
ClockTZ::ClockTZ(ClockUTC clockUTC, int offset)
{
    this->clockUTC = clockUTC;
```

The child class constructor should, instead, contruct its parent class correctly:

```
ClockTZ::ClockTZ(ClockUTC clockUTC, int offset)
       : ClockUTC{clockUTC}
{
```

That's it (or, maybe "`ClockUTC(clockUTC)`", if you are using an old compiler).

> and it is calling it's empty constructor and setting the hour to 0
>   instead of it's value + the offset as intended.

Of course it does. Your child class never calls the parent class's constructor, and instead constructs a duplicate member of the child class, that happens to be the same class as its parent class.

Your C++ book should have more information and examples of correctly constructing parent classes.

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out that `clockUTC.setHour(clockUTC.getHour() + offset);` is calling `setHour` on the parameter passed in and not on the class object.

Comment: Okay thanks. I tried, but there is a small problem:
Check the update on the question one more time please, at the very end.

Comment: That's because you also failed to implement the equivalent of  "clockUTC.setHour(clockUTC.getHour() + offset);", in the corrected code. You completely removed this logic. You need to implement the equivalent logic in the constructor. Things don't happen automatically in C++. You have to implement them. If you have to adjust the hour.

Comment: I had it setHour(clockUTC.getHour() + offset), after changing it to the line you told me about, it will always be 9. I updated the question with my constructor so that you can check it in case I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: I understand you. So there is no way to do it without modifying the main class?

Comment: At the very least, declare the parent class's methods as virtual and override them in the child class.